# Check a records value against another table MySql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a MySql database. In **TableA** I hold information about products given out for today and the group they belong to (if they belong to one), in **TableB** I hold a check list of all the products that should be given out if they are in one of the groups.

```
    TableA  

id  Group   ProductNumber
1   Group3  1234
2   Group2  4321
3   Group2  14235
4   Group3  15423
5   Group3  14236
6   Group2  172883
7   Group1  198334
8   Group2  90399209
9   Group1  78877
```

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmMWS.png)

I basically need to do this in MySql:
Check to see if the product given out was the right one according to table B.
In table A it tells you what group the ProductNumber should belong to, so if its in that group in tableB then its ok. If not then bring it back in the recordset.

Im sure theres an easy way to do this, I just cannot figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

At first, your schema of `Table 2` might not the right DB schema. I suggest you something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE2` (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_id INT NOT NULL,
group_id ENUM(1,2,3) NOT NULL,
manufacturer_id INT NOT NULL,
number INT NOT NULL,
...
)
```

And sample of your first row in `Table2`

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE2`  (product_id, group_id, manufacturer_id, product_number)
VALUE (1, 3, 1, 1234);
```

Then it would be much easy to do your job done.
If you want to erase wrong data in `Table1` realtime, then use `MySQL TRIGGER`.
If you want to erase wrong data in certain time, then make `PROCEDURE` and run whenever you want.

And following is checking query whether rows in `Table1` is right data or not.

```
SELECT t1.id, IF(t1.group=t2.group_id, 'Right', 'Wrong') AS 'Check'
FROM `TABLE1` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `TABLE2` AS t2 ON t1.product_number=t2.product_number
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have no control over the schema of the table as its existing data :-(